# How to create XAMPP login for local wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, localhost, local

I have taken over for another employee who was the WordPress web support person.

I found XAMPP installed on my local computer. I've gone through a few tutorials online and XAMPP does seem to work. There is one issue. When I type:

localhost/wordpress/

...a WP site with an installed theme displays. It looks like this was the last theme my predecessor was working on before he left. So then I typed:

localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php

...and tried my 3 different WP logins and passwords. I need to be able to get into the local WP so I can work offline with it.  I didn't think any of my working WP logins would work but tried it anyway. None worked.

So what I need to find out now is how can I create a login and password for this local host so I can then go in and start working on WP offline?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: xampp n wordpress both are different things, what u want exactly?

Comment: You don't have correct credentials I believe?

Answer (score 0):

You open local phpmyadmin,

then go the database which ur predecessor was working, then go the "table_prefix"_users table,

there add the username as "some_username" and copy the password from someother wordpress installation and paste to that user password. it will work.

For example, my password is "admin", in my wordpress table wp_users table its saved as "$P$B2AnxKNn5VLdGBTeHTn0cQO29mu3Qu0". So if i copy and paste this encrypted one as my password for another user. It works if i type it as "admin".

So try this. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi see the screen shot here - http://designerandpublisher.com/images/wp_users.jpg - this appears to be the login from the person before me.  Can I just edit this one to suit my own name and etc?  Also does the PWD have to be so long?  Thanks much for your help.

Comment: Yes. You can change the "user_login" as the "username_you_need" and the "user_pass" as the "encrypted_form_of_password_from_any_other_wordpress_installation" or from a new installation

Comment: Hi - ok I just did this.  I made my login "myname" and I made the password very simple like "WPTest@123" and saved it.  The record updated but then I tried to login and it did not work.  It said the password did not work so I don't know if the simple password is too simple?  The login screen for this is at - localhost/wordpress/wp-admin - so it seems like I'm at the right place.  Any ideas?

Comment: Don give password as "WPTest@123". Perform a new wordpress installation separately. Then give the same user name & password... Then from that user_pass field, copy the encrypted data and paste to the old table and check with the data..

Comment: oh boy i hate this - why does it have to be so complicated.  in the above screen shot i put everything back the way it was including the long password and previous guy's user name.  i tried "admin" and long PWD, then his user name and long PWD and those don't work either.  also do i really need to re-install WP to make this work?  it seems to be working i just can't login as the admin.